# Convert blanks in a column to NAs

Tags: r, assign

I'm trying to put NA into the blank spaces in the AWC_Code column in this dataframe (there's 4 rows here but I have 4k of them).

```
Region, LocationID, DistrictID,SubDistrictID,Area,AWC_Code
Yukon, 1,2,3,2,106-2
Yukon,1,2,4,5,
Kodiak,4,5,6,8,
Kodiak,6,8,9,5,333-1
```

Comment: Can you please `dput(your.example.dataframe)`? Edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44143266/edit

Comment: If it's an S4 object, try `str(loc)` to see how it's structured.  You might need to use `@` instead of `$`.  Also, take the quotes off of the `"NA"` -- just `NA` is needed.

Comment: @MattTyers It says its a character. Should it be a factor?

Comment: @Juliet It shouldn't be an issue whether that column is a character or factor.  Since it was complaining about the S4 slot, I was wondering if `loc` might have some kind of S4 structuring, in which case a "typical" `df$column` column selection might not work.

Comment: @MattTyers I ended up using this: loc$AWC_Code <- sub("^$", NA, loc1$AWC_Code) and it ended up working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, try this:

```
df$AWC_Code[is.null(df$AWC_Code)] <- "NA"
```